# How to turn an array of values into another indexed array?

Tags: php, indexed

this is a follow up to another question which I was instructed to split up. I have different set of columns and their values some which have values, some which don't. For example:

```
$vCountries ['country1'] = "Value of country1";
$vCountries ['country2'] = "Value of country2";
$vCountries ['country3'] = "";
$vCountries ['country4'] = "Value of country4";
$vCountries ['country5'] = "";

...through to

$vCountries ['country50'] = "Value of country50";
```

I would like to generate the following code example (only when it contains a value):

```
<th id="country1">Value of country1</th>
<th id="country2">Value of country2</th>
<th id="country4">Value of country4</th>

...
```

Since all country ID's are generically named with only an index to differ them, I would like these headings to be generated dynamically.

Someone has suggested the following code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; ++$i) {
$vCountries['country' . $i] = "Value of country " . $i;}
```

But firstly, I don't understand how it is working and how I can parse it to the code at the top because for now it only prints array array array etc. and the "Value of country .$i" is not generic and indexed, it is an actual value different for each country, so I would still have to list it manually, no?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will do it.

```
foreach($vCountries as $id => $value)
{
    if($value)
    {
        echo "<th id=\"$id\">$value</th>";
    }
}
```

This outputs only entries with values.  Each id is output as the `<th>` id, and each value is displayed inside the `<th>` tag.

Comment: @Murilo:  Next time fix it instead of deleting it.  Your answer added value to the conversation, it just needed a little tweak.

Comment: Ok thank you! I am new here so I am learning how to use this tool. The guys here are very fast, when I started to write my answer, there was not answers yet, so as you answered I thought my answer is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This generates the code you want :

```
foreach ($vCountries as $key => $value)
{
    if (strlen($value) > 0)
        echo "<th id=\"$key\">$value</th>";
}
```

Comment: I think that using `strlen()` isn't good because if `$value` is big you can get loss of performance.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to generate the said HTML code from the array, which is already defined, then this may be a solution for you:

```
// Loop the array
foreach ($vCountries as $key => $value) {
    // If value is not empty
    if (!empty($value)) {
        // display the line
        echo '<th id="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</th>'."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies guys, I have tried Surreal Dreams solution and it seems to be working but as a result I have encountered the problem of having to check the excel file (it reads from) if the values are there. So I need to access the cell and check it so it will have to be another question bear with me. This site is confusing :)